# deep copy or clone of a UIComponent

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I tried this:

```
registerClassAlias("mx.core.UIComponent",UIComponent);
var ob:UIComponent= UIComponent(ObjectUtil.copy(flexUI));//where flexUI is source UIComponent
```

But it did not work. returning me null in ob

I also tried:

```
var canvas:Canvas = new canvas();
canvas.createComponentFromDescriptor(flexUI.descriptor,false);
```

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't clone DisplayObject. Your best bet is recreate it with same parameters, for example, have a custom class for it, create new instance and feed same data into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var canvas:Canvas = new canvas();
canvas.createComponentFromDescriptor(flexUI.descriptor,false);
canvas.validateNow();
```